# Caffe Deep Learning Library example

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

Here is an example from
http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html

I'm kind of lost. What am I supposed to infer from this example?

```
// Assuming that data are on the CPU initially, and we have a blob.
const Dtype* foo;
Dtype* bar;
foo = blob.gpu_data(); // data copied cpu->gpu.
foo = blob.cpu_data(); // no data copied since both have up-to-date contents.
bar = blob.mutable_gpu_data(); // no data copied.
// ... some operations ...
bar = blob.mutable_gpu_data(); // no data copied when we are still on GPU.
foo = blob.cpu_data(); // data copied gpu->cpu, since the gpu side has modified the data
foo = blob.gpu_data(); // no data copied since both have up-to-date contents
bar = blob.mutable_cpu_data(); // still no data copied.
bar = blob.mutable_gpu_data(); // data copied cpu->gpu.
bar = blob.mutable_cpu_data(); // data copied gpu->cpu.
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is to explain a feature of Caffe's Blob class shielding the user from the details of CPU<->GPU memory transfer.

My attempt at elaborating on the comments in the code:

It assumes you've already declared a Blob object and populated with data. What the data represents is irrelevant. The actual declaration of the Blob object and its initialization are missing from this snippet.

```
// Assuming that data are on the CPU initially, and we have a blob.
const Dtype* foo;
Dtype* bar;
```

Since the data populating the blob resides in CPU memory, making use of it on a GPU device requires a transfer.

```
foo = blob.gpu_data(); // data copied cpu->gpu.
```

But if you're getting copying that same data to somewhere else on CPU memory, the Blob object won't have to perform the expensive copy operations required for CPU<->GPU transfers.

```
foo = blob.cpu_data(); // no data copied since both have up-to-date contents.
```

Initializing the 'bar' object with data residing in GPU memory. It's already copied them once. No need to repeat the costly copy operations.

```
bar = blob.mutable_gpu_data(); // no data copied.
// ... some operations ...
bar = blob.mutable_gpu_data(); // no data copied when we are still on GPU.
```

The Blob class keeps track of whether the CPU and CPU copies are identical or if one was modified, requiring a renewed copy in order to keep them identical.

```
foo = blob.cpu_data(); // data copied gpu->cpu, since the gpu side has modified the data
foo = blob.gpu_data(); // no data copied since both have up-to-date contents
```

Now we're just going back and forth and seeing what will trigger a copy and will fall back on a cached copy of the data.

```
bar = blob.mutable_cpu_data(); // still no data copied.
bar = blob.mutable_gpu_data(); // data copied cpu->gpu.
bar = blob.mutable_cpu_data(); // data copied gpu->cpu.
```